# Gson-xml deserialize list<object> in onother list<object>

Tags: java, android, gson

i use [Gson-xml](https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml) library to cast xml to object. this is my xml:

```
<GetSentMessageListResponse xmlns="http://ICAN.ir/x/mWebServices/">
                    <GetSentMessageListResult>
                            <Message>
                                <ID>2620</ID>
                                <Subject>test</Subject>
                                <Description>&amp;lt;div style=&amp;quot;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20pt&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;</Description>
                                <SentDate>7/10/2018 5:04:40 PM</SentDate>
                                <Receivers>
                                    <Receiver>
                                        <RoleID>393</RoleID>
                                        <UserID>717</UserID>
                                        <UserName>f</UserName>
                                        <NativeID />
                                    </Receiver>
                                    <Receiver>
                                        <RoleID>786</RoleID>
                                        <UserID>5</UserID>
                                        <UserName>mm</UserName>
                                        <NativeID />
                                    </Receiver>
                                </Receivers>
                                <MessageFiles />
                            </Message>
                    </GetSentMessageListResult>
                <strErrorMsg />
            </GetSentMessageListResponse>
```

and blow are my class:

```
public class StructureMessageListResultOP {
private StructureMessageList GetRecieveMessageListResult;
private StructureMessageList GetSentMessageListResult;
private String StrErrorMsg;

public StructureMessageList getGetRecieveMessageListResult() {
    return GetRecieveMessageListResult;
}

public void setGetRecieveMessageListResult(StructureMessageList getRecieveMessageListResult) {
    GetRecieveMessageListResult = getRecieveMessageListResult;
}

public StructureMessageList getGetSentMessageListResult() {
    return GetSentMessageListResult;
}

public void setGetSentMessageListResult(StructureMessageList getSentMessageListResult) {
    GetSentMessageListResult = getSentMessageListResult;
}

public String getStrErrorMsg() {
    return StrErrorMsg;
}

public void setStrErrorMsg(String strErrorMsg) {
    StrErrorMsg = strErrorMsg;
}


//____________________________________________________
public class StructureMessageList {
    List<StructureMessageListBodyOP> Message;

    public List<StructureMessageListBodyOP> getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    public void setMessage(List<StructureMessageListBodyOP> message) {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class StructureMessageListBodyOP {
private int ID;
private String Subject;
private String Description;
private String SentDate;
StructureReceiverList Receivers;

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return Subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    Subject = subject;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public String getSentDate() {
    return SentDate;
}

public void setSentDate(String sentDate) {
    SentDate = sentDate;
}

public StructureReceiverList getReceivers() {
    return Receivers;
}

public void setReceivers(StructureReceiverList receivers) {
    Receivers = receivers;
}

//-------------------------- **ReceiverList** -------------------------------
public class StructureReceiverList {
   List<StructureReceiverOP> Receiver;

    public List<StructureReceiverOP> getReceiver() {
        return Receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(List<StructureReceiverOP> receiver) {
        Receiver = receiver;
    }
}
//___________________________________________________________________________
```

}

public class StructureReceiverOP {

```
private int RoleID;
private int UserID;
private String UserName;

public int getRoleID() {
    return RoleID;
}

public void setRoleID(int roleID) {
    RoleID = roleID;
}

public int getUserID() {
    return UserID;
}

public void setUserID(int userID) {
    UserID = userID;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}
```

}

my problem is Gson-xml can not cast inerList and when write

```
List<StructureReceiverOP> Receiver;
```

set error and can not cast.

please help me i got tired.

I tried it anyway, but did not.
I thought the library was very powerful, but it was not like that.
If you know a better library that can do that, tell me. Mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried many time and finaly found another library which use the java core.
i used Simple-xml.you can use it from this [Link](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php)